# Number of Channels in category

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a Join to Create System and want to name the channel with numbers. So if there are alredy two channels in this category, the third one would be named "Channel 3".

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

channel = after.channel

v_channels = [939457151146012672, 942088196576145418]
v_categories = [939457129625059329, 942087974244483112]

if channel.id in v_channels:
    guild = after.channel.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=v_categories[1])
    count = len( #number of channels in category 
    channelname = f"Channel [ {count + 1} ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.htmt#discord.CategoryChannel.channels) attribute.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

  channel = after.channel

  v_channels = [
    939457151146012672, 
    942088196576145418
  ]
  v_categories = [
    939457129625059329, 
    942087974244483112
  ]

  if channel.id in v_channels:
    guild = after.channel.guild
    category = discord.utils.get(
      guild.categories, 
      id=v_categories[1]
    )
    count = len(category.channels)
    channelname = f"Channel [ {count + 1} ]"
```

Comment: Thanks, but now If two users create two talk they are named Channel 1 and Channel 2. If now Channel 1 deletes and someone else creates another channel there are both named Channel 2

Comment: then you can instead use a variable to keep track of the currently open channels and reset it to 0 whenver the category is empty (you can check if the category is empty on deletion of the channel) however this is flawed in the sense that in an active server the category might never be empty leading to high channel numbers despite the lower number channels having been deleted

Comment: a better solution imo would be to have an array of say 1 to 10 and on channel creation you check for the minimum value in the array and then pop it to create the channel and re append it on deletion